# TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Vue'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In an attempt to learn TypeScript and VueJS I am attempting to port the [Vue Material Dashboard](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-material-dashboard) to Typescript. There are plenty of errors which seem related to types not being declared. In an effort to shim the types in Vue and declare them for the Material Dashboard I followed a suggest in [this thread](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/662#issuecomment-308937275). I put this in a `shims-material.d.ts` file, and included the [official `shim-vue.d.ts`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/types). However, this creates an error that is outside my razor-thin experience:

> TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Vue'.

There are obviously a lot of Google hits for this, but they are generally about other, specific frameworks and I'm having difficulty mapping the wide variety of suggestions to this case. It is clear that these two declarations cannot co-exist, but I don't understand the difference between the module declaration with a namespace and one without. I certainly don't know how to merge the `material` const into the `*.vue` module. (For that matter, I don't quite understand the difference between declaring a module in the slash delimited form `vue/types/vue` vs the pattern match form `*.vue`, and in what way these can or should coexist.)

*What is the right way to merge these two declarations so they don't have a collision?*

The declaration in my `shims-material.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  namespace Vue {
    const material: {
      registerTheme(name: string | { [key: string]: ThemeType }, spec?: ThemeType): void,
      setCurrentTheme(name: string): void
    };
  }
}
```

The declaration in my `shims-vue.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  // noinspection JSDuplicatedDeclaration
  export default Vue;
}
```